# Testing website overload

Tags: testing, web, overloading, asp.net

I have an Asp.net website using SQL Server. I want to make a website overload test like http://loadimpact.com/ How can perform this test by myself and see my website performance?

I want to see max users, instant traffic, error pages etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do performance/stress testing with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Visual Studio Test Professional 2010 which include a new application called [Microsoft Test Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409.aspx) to help you define and manage your testing effort by using test plans.

A good start would be by creating a [LoadTestPlugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to do what you want at various points in the load test.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a tool that will generate load on your website.

[Here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) is a list of open source performance testing tools - I am sure at least one will fit your needs.

You do need to remember that this can take a lot of bandwidth and you have to ensure that your site and the machine/s generating the load have enough of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) if you want to test to see how much your web application can handle. In particular checkout the [user manual](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/index.html). As Oded mentioned, you'll have to make sure you have enough bandwidth between the machine that is running the app and the machine that is running JMeter.

In many cases, getting a co-located box in the same rack will give you virtually unlimited bandwidth for testing. Sometimes you can even run JMeter on the same machine as your application or on a virtual machine on the same physical hardware.  The downside is that JMeter does use some resources, so you won't know exactly how much your app can handle, but it should give you a pretty good idea of how many users to expect before running into trouble.